# Client-side Extension to Autoformat Code Snippets

Tags: feature-request, edits, code-formatting

Very often when a new question comes into Stack Overflow, it doesn't meet a certain quality bar. So if the question is salvageable, I take to editing it for clarity, formatting, grammar, etc.

Consider that a post has content like:

```
var potatoCheck = function()    {
        var x=4
 if(x=="4")return "hello"
    else return "potato"}
```

Ideally, I could select the content, and run a macro to auto-format it. This is different than just the `<Ctrl>-K` to auto-indent.

So my question is: is there any generic (or Stack Overflow-specific) browser extension capable of doing this kind of beautification? Perhaps a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) / Tampermonkey script?

Comment: Did you check on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/search?q=code)?

Comment: It's more steps but if you don't find something appropriate, copy/pasting into a fiddle/pen site and using their Tidy function also works.

Comment: This is really hard to do in a language generic way.  There are languages like make where the type and amount of spacing is meaningful.

Comment: If it's JavaScript (or really any language that formats like JavaScript), HTML, or CSS, I usually open up Stack Snippets, paste the code in the appropriate spot and click the Tidy button, then cut and paste back in. Takes me all of a half-minute at most.